# Initializing IPOPT when using pyomo parmest

Tags: pyomo, ipopt

I am learning to use pyomo parmest. I am trying to recreate the following parameter estimation [example](https://sites.engineering.ucsb.edu/~jbraw/chemreacfun/fig-html/appendix/fig-A-10.html). The code that I created is in the following [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/notesofdabbler/learn_pyomo/blob/master/wk_parmest/ABC_parmest.ipynb). IPOPT stops with the message of maximum iterations exceeded when using collocation but solves with finite difference discretization. Since it is suggested that collocation is typically more robust, I would like to know what I might be doing wrong in using the collocation discretization.

Answer (score 0):

I had originally used number of collocation points in discretization ncp = 4. When I changed ncp = 2, IPOPT ran without issues. The updated ipython notebook is in this [location](https://github.com/notesofdabbler/learn_pyomo/blob/master/wk_parmest/ABC_parmest_base.ipynb).